# How to get the roots of these equations with flexible parameters by fsolve function?

Tags: matlab

I write two mfiles to solve the roots **t** and **p** of two equations. There is a flexible parameter **n** used in equation which changes from 1 to 100. Now the code can only solve the roots as **n** = 100 for 100 time instead of 1 to 100. How to correct it?

file 1:

```
function q=CSMA(x)
      m=5;
      W=32;

      p=x(1);
      t=x(2);

  for n = 1:100;

      q(1)=(1-2*p)*(1+W)+p*W*(1-(2*p)^m)-2*(1-2*p)/t;
      q(2)=(1-(1-t)^(n-1))-p;

  end
end
```

file 2:

```
N = 100;
the_roots = zeros(1, N);

for n = 1:N
    y = fsolve('CSMA', [0.1, 0.1], optimset('Display', 'off'));
    p = y(1);
    t = y(2);
    the_roots(n)= t;
end

figure;
plot(the_roots, 'b-');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the variable `n` to your function as a parameter. You could for example change your `CSMA` function like this:

```
function q=CSMA(x,n)
      m=5;
      W=32;

      p=x(1);
      t=x(2);

      q(1)=(1-2*p)*(1+W)+p*W*(1-(2*p)^m)-2*(1-2*p)/t;
      q(2)=(1-(1-t)^(n-1))-p;

end
```

And then the optimization could look like this using a function handle:

```
N = 100;
the_roots = zeros(1, N);

for n = 1:N
    f = @(x) CSMA(x,n);
    y = fsolve(f, [0.1, 0.1], optimset('Display', 'off'));
    p = y(1);
    t = y(2);
    the_roots(n)= t;
end

figure;
plot(the_roots, 'b-');
```

The plotted output looks like this:

[image: Plotted output of roots]

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful.

Comment: Glad I could help!